# Defining ngTable table header title attribute

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

In a default ngTable the title attribute of the headers is a single blank as in title=" ", which causes strange hover artifacts in IE and is not a good value from the accessibility perspective either. 
How can I define the title attribute of the table headers?

The blank title is caused by the headerTitle attribute of the column defaults in app.factory('ngTableColumn'):

```
var defaults = {
    'class': function(){ return ''; },
    filter: function(){ return false; },
    filterData: angular.noop,
    headerTemplateURL: function(){ return false; },
    headerTitle: function(){ return ' '; },
    sortable: function(){ return false; },
    show: function(){ return true; },
    title: function(){ return ' '; },
    titleAlt: function(){ return ''; }
};
```

Can I redefine the headerTitle function which is used to build the column?

See also [Issue 561](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/561)

Comment: It seems like it has already been [fixed](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/dist/ng-table.js#L698) in latest version. Have you tried to update?

Comment: It also seems like adding this attribute to the ngTable should help: `header-title="function() { return ''; }"` (in case you don't want to update)

Comment: It is not fixed in 0.5.4. Besides, an empty title attribute is not quite what I need, I want to define the title, possibly dynamically, or at least modify it

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out that the code has been changed to return an empty string as title rather than a blank.

Answer (score 2):

One can specifically set the title attribute by adding "header-title" with a double quoted + single quoted value to the td:

```
<table ng-table class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td data-title="'Name'" header-title="'Foo'">{{user.name}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Age'" header-title="'Bar'">{{user.age}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The header-title value on the td and all other defaults are evaluated in the [directive definition](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/b6d5d0bfeef923c617081ffe80a0266d7fb4aa33/src/browser/ngTable.directive.ts#L118) and win over the defaults mentioned in the original question.